# Is there a way to make PMD ruleset ignore Hashcode & Equals methods for Cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: java, hashcode, pmd, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm already know about the various annotation or comment I can add into my code, but it's not what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for a way that only have me modify the [CyclomaticComplexity](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/codesize.html#CyclomaticComplexity) rule.
I don't seen any option in the rule, although it seems like a rather common need. And there doesnt seems to be a xpath since it uses a java class.

If nothing better can you override the java class used for the rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there is no specific option for this rule, to explicitly ignore `hashCode` and `equals` methods. However, it should be possible now via [suppressions](http://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.4.1/usage/suppressing.html). Every rule has a "violationSuppressXPath" property - and it seems, that this is used for this rule in a way, that it should work with this use case: It's not only applied for the violations, but also while analyzing the source code.

Here's the source code for [CyclomaticComplexityRule](http://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.4.1/pmd-java/xref/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/codesize/CyclomaticComplexityRule.html) which inherits from [StdCyclomaticComplexityRule](http://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.4.1/pmd-java/xref/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/codesize/StdCyclomaticComplexityRule.html). If you look at [line 188](http://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.4.1/pmd-java/xref/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/codesize/StdCyclomaticComplexityRule.html#L188), you'll see that the method node is checked for any suppressions. If the method is suppressed, then it is not analyzed and <strike>should not be counted towards the class complexity.</strike> [See update below].

A possible XPath expression for `violationSuppressXPath` might look like this:

```
./MethodDeclarator[@Image='hashCode' or @Image='equals']
```

You'll need to use a [custom ruleset](http://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.4.1/customizing/howtomakearuleset.html), in order to configure the property. You're ruleset might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Custom ruleset"
    xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
  <description>CyclomaticComplexity ignoring hashCode and equals</description>

    <rule ref="rulesets/java/codesize.xml/CyclomaticComplexity">
        <properties>
            <property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="./MethodDeclarator[@Image='hashCode' or @Image='equals']"/>
        </properties>
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

Please note, that my examples use PMD 5.4.x - which is much newer than PMD 4.3 you referred to. The rule organization has been changed in order to support multiple languages - this means, the rule reference for PMD 4.3 would be just `rulesets/codesize.xml/CyclomaticComplexity`.

**Update (2016-05-20)**

With the configured violationSuppressXPath property, the methods "equals" and "hashCode" are not highlighted anymore. Only the violation messages are suppressed. *However* the content of the method still does count to the total complexity of the class, so that any conditions/if statements/loops/etc. are checked (this is because `super.visit()` is called before suppression at [line 186](http://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.4.1/pmd-java/xref/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/codesize/StdCyclomaticComplexityRule.html#L186)) and because the `isSuppressed` check only understands annotations.

This means, while the method itself is not highlighted anymore, the class is, because it contains a complex method.

The only way to completely ignore the equals/hashCode methods is, to annotate these with

```
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.CyclomaticComplexity")
```

Then, they are totally ignored and really do not count towards the class complexity.

Comment: what would be excellent is the ability to put the method names 'equals' and 'hashCode' in the XML at the top level, similar to files that should be ignored. Probably a big ask, right?

Comment: I have annotated my `equals()` and `hashCode()` with `@SuppressWarnings("PMD.CyclomaticComplexity")` but I am still seeing the warnings on the class: `The class 'Order' has a Modified Cyclomatic Complexity of 3 (Highest = 11).` and similarly for `Standard Cyclomatic Comlexity`.

Comment: @Adam Old post, but I came across this as well. To address the `Standard Cyclomatic Complexity` and `Modified Cyclomatic Complexity`, you can also use `@SuppressWarnings` and include both `"PMD.ModifiedCyclomaticComplexity"` and `"PMD.StdCyclomaticComplexity"`.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

```
 // Ignore PMD warning that equals and hashCode should be defined, while we need only custom equals.
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.OverrideBothEqualsAndHashcode")
class DefineYourClass...
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to ignore hashcode and equals for complexity PMD rule, by modifying the PMD rule itself.